# Kotlin spring не видит зависимости модуля

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle

Доброго времени суток.

Создал многомодульный проект gradle.
Главный build:

```
group = "com.company"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

Главный settings:

```
rootProject.name = "company-app"

include("app-model")
include("telegram-bot")
```

У меня есть 2 модуля в проекте. Модуль `telegram-bot` использует бины модуля `app-model`.

`build.gradle.kts` модуля `telegram-bot`:

```
dependencies {
    api(project(":app-model"))
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("com.github.pengrad:java-telegram-bot-api:4.9.0")
    implementation("com.vdurmont:emoji-java:5.1.1")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude(group = "org.junit.vintage", module = "junit-vintage-engine")
    }
}
```

При попытке внедрить bean, возникает ошибка в intellij idea:

`Could not autowire. No beans of 'TelegramUserService' type found.`

При этом пакеты не подсвечиваются красным цветом. При попытке запуска возникает следующее:
[image: ошибка]

Подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону копать? Второй вечер убиваю время на сборку... Заранее благодарю за ответы.

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/). Вроде как надо добавить аннотаций типа таких, с указанием какие пакеты сканировать на предмет зависимостей: `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackageClasses={…​})`

Comment: Idea видит класс, но не удается запустить проект из-за ошибки `Unresolved reference: appmodel`..

Comment: Попробуйте вот такое: https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl-samples/issues/393

Comment: Юра, большое человеческое спасибо тебе. Помогло все же, если указать только для общего модуля. Жму твою крепкую руку программиста. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Огромная благодарность Юрию за помощь.

Помогло добавление в общий модуль:

```
tasks.withType<BootJar> {
    enabled = false
}
tasks.withType<Jar> {
    enabled = true
}
```